# How to change font-size by limiting it to increase or decrease twice using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I'm able to change the font size once: decrease (-A), default (A) or Increase (A+). If I click the buttons more than once, it does nothing.

What I want is to be able to increase/decrease the font size but limiting it to clicking twice so the font size doesn't go beyond -/+ 150%.

Example: When I click on `-A`, the font size reduces to 0.75em. I want this to further reduce it to 0.5em if someone clicks it again but that should be the minimum size it can go. Likewise, font size is increased to 1.25em when `A+` is clicked but should not increase beyond 1.5em if a user clicks multiple times.

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/etfcdu10/**

```js
  var cont = document.getElementById("container");
  function changeSizeByBtn(size) {
    cont.style.fontSize = size + "em";
  }
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;  
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
p {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(0.75)" name="btn1">-A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(1)" name="btn2">A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(1.25)" name="btn3">A+</button>
<hr />
<div id="container">
  <h1>This is the title</h1>
  <h2>This is a sub title</h2>
  <p>I need to increase the texts here by clicking on A+ button and decrease them by clicking -A button above. <br />
The problem here is that it increase/decrease only once. I want it to increase or decrease twice by say 25%. Not Thrice but just twice. How can I go about doing this?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This just the code for the current state.

Comment: what is the purpose of the A button? just reset it to default size?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, it is there to just reset it to default size.

Comment: what happens if I decrease the size twice and then I want to increase the size using the A+ button. Does that mean that I can return it to normal size with 2 clicks and then another 2 clicks to increase the size further before reaching the limit?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, you're right. In such cases, the user must click A+ four times so the size of the font goes to 1.5em from 0.5em. Thank you for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `sizeChange` is `1`, then that means the reset button was pressed to return the text to normal size.

`fontSizeMultiplier` is updated by adding `sizeChange` to it, it can be positive or a negative number depending on if you are increasing or decreasing the size.

Keep track of increase and decrease counters separately `numIncreases` for increase counter and `numDecreases` for the decrease counter.

with this code, limit the counters

```
if (numIncreases >= 2 && sizeChange < 0) {
  numIncreases = 0;
} else if (numDecreases >= 2 && sizeChange > 0) {
  numDecreases = 0;
}
```

that to prevent the user from decreasing the text too much or the other way around

and finally apply the font size change like you were already doing

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
var fontSizeMultiplier = 1;
var numIncreases = 0;
var numDecreases = 0;

function changeSizeByBtn(sizeChange) {
  if (sizeChange === 1) {
    fontSizeMultiplier = 1;
    numIncreases = 0;
    numDecreases = 0;
  } else {
    fontSizeMultiplier += sizeChange;

    if (fontSizeMultiplier < 0.5) {
      fontSizeMultiplier = 0.5;
    } else if (fontSizeMultiplier > 1.5) {
      fontSizeMultiplier = 1.5;
    }

    if (sizeChange > 0) {
      numIncreases++;
    } else if (sizeChange < 0) {
      numDecreases++;
    }

    if (numIncreases >= 2 && sizeChange < 0) {
      numIncreases = 0;
    } else if (numDecreases >= 2 && sizeChange > 0) {
      numDecreases = 0;
    }
  }

  cont.style.fontSize = fontSizeMultiplier + "em";
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;  
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
p {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(-0.25)" name="btn1">-A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(1)" name="btn2">A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(0.25)" name="btn3">A+</button>
<hr />
<div id="container">
  <h1>This is the title</h1>
  <h2>This is a sub title</h2>
  <p>I need to increase the texts here by clicking on A+ button and decrease them by clicking -A button above. <br />
The problem here is that it increase/decrease only once. I want it to increase or decrease twice by say 25%. Not Thrice but just twice. How can I go about doing this?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: np, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the size, make your function change it by the specified amount. Start by changing the values in your HTML:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(-0.25)" name="btn1">-A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(0)" name="btn2">A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(0.25)" name="btn3">A+</button>
```

Then, modify your function to change the size accordingly:

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
function changeSizeByBtn(size) {
  // Start by checking if the value provided is zero, which means we want to reset the size
  if (size === 0) {
      cont.style.fontSize = "1em";
      return;
  }
  // Next, we will make sure that the new size doesn't exceed our boundaries (in this case, 0.5em and 1.5em)
  const newSize = parseFloat(cont.style.fontSize.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)[0]) + size;
  if (newSize <= 1.5 && newSize >= 0.5) {
    // It doesn't, so lets change the size
    cont.style.fontSize = newSize + "em";
  }
}
```

Here's the final code:

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
function changeSizeByBtn(size) {
  // Start by checking if the value provided is zero, which means we want to reset the size
  if (size === 0) {
      cont.style.fontSize = "1em";
      return;
  }
  // Next, we will make sure that the new size doesn't exceed our boundaries (in this case, 0.5em and 1.5em)
  const newSize = parseFloat(cont.style.fontSize.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)[0]) + size;
  if (newSize <= 1.5 && newSize >= 0.5) {
    // It doesn't, so lets change the size
    cont.style.fontSize = newSize + "em";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;  
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
p {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(-0.25)" name="btn1">-A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(0)" name="btn2">A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(0.25)" name="btn3">A+</button>
<hr />
<div id="container" style="font-size: 1em;">
  <h1>This is the title</h1>
  <h2>This is a sub title</h2>
  <p>I need to increase the texts here by clicking on A+ button and decrease them by clicking -A button above. <br />
The problem here is that it increase/decrease only once. I want it to increase or decrease twice by say 25%. Not Thrice but just twice. How can I go about doing this?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain `parseFloat(cont.style.fontSize.match(/\d+\.?(?:\d+)?/)[0])` and why this code is necessary? Thank You.

Comment: That is a regular expression. This is a way for me to grab only the number from the font size. See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/amyrPY/2

Comment: The code is necessary to extract just the number from the font size style property of an element. When you set the font size in CSS, it usually includes units like "px" or "em" (e.g., "16px" or "1.5em"). However, when you're working with JavaScript and want to perform calculations or comparisons with font sizes, you typically want just the number without the units.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only allowed font size changes to occur once per button click.
The 'changeSizeByBtn' function represents the change in font size relative to the current size.

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
var currentFontSize = 1; // Initial font size
var clickCount = 0;

function changeSizeByBtn(sizeChange) {
  clickCount++;
  
  // Limiting the clicks to two
  if (clickCount > 2) return;

  // If sizeChange is 0, reset font size to default
  if (sizeChange === 0) {
    currentFontSize = 1;
  } else {
    // Updating the font size
    currentFontSize += sizeChange;
    
    // Limiting the font size to 0.5em minimum and 1.5em maximum
    if (currentFontSize < 0.5) currentFontSize = 0.5;
    if (currentFontSize > 1.5) currentFontSize = 1.5;
  }

  cont.style.fontSize = currentFontSize + "em";

  // Resetting click count after two clicks
  if (clickCount === 2) clickCount = 0;
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;  
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
p {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(-0.25)" name="btn1">-A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(0)" name="btn2">A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeSizeByBtn(0.25)" name="btn3">A+</button> 


<hr />
<div id="container">
<h1>This is the title</h1>
<h2>This is a sub title</h2>
<p>I need to increase the texts here by clicking on A+ button and decrease them by clicking -A button above. <br />
The problem here is that it increase/decrease only once. I want it to increase or decrease twice by say 10%. Not Thrice but just twice. How can I go about doing this?
</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a clean code as well. Hope someone finds your solution helpful and can learn from it.

Comment: You are welcome, trying to make it relate to your initial code and you didn't accept mine :/ . Glad you are able to find a solution.

Comment: I'm so sorry Beth but know that I'm very thankful for the help. I learned a lot from clean your code.